# Shading Imported VDB to look more like Embergen Shading

Tags: node-editor, shader-nodes, volumetrics

This may not be the right forum. But I was wondering if someone knew a good node set up for shading a VDB simulation to have "translucency" like it has in Embergen.

[image]

this is kinda what I'm looking for. Disregard the colors, I'm more interesting in the translucency of the flame itself.

[image]

And this is what I have now... The flames appear more thick and not so stylized/ Real. Again, disregard the color of the flame. I know the colors aren't very photorealistic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick here is to let the flame not "burn" directly from the beginning. In reality, combustion gases leave the burning surface and then ignite later a little more or less above the surface.

To simulate this, you can set a larger range on the right side of the color ramp (which you use for the flame color) to black. The best position is highly depending on your simulation and the look you want to achieve, so I cannot give you specific values - this is just to show you a direction in which to go.

[image: flame transparency]